# N game tutorial collision detection convex/concave

Tags: math, collision-detection, physics, game-physics

Am following N game tutorial for handling collision detection for one of my game , one thing which is unclear in this approach is they were talking about separate axis theorem on this page but if you see in the implementation(Tutorial A) no where I could see separate axis was handled. From the below URL, section `--= round shapes =--`  talks about how to handle collision between AABB vs convex/concave shapes.
http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html#section2

I have the basic idea of vectors and separate axis implementation but not this approach , what I understood from this tutorial is the whole N game world is made of 5 - 8 different shapes (tile) each tile in turn rotated horizontally/vertically which gives 4 combination facing left,right,top & bottom. These facing info is stored in each tile which is signx,y.

obj - is the player (rectangle)
t - tile 
x,y - bounding box projection

**Implementation : Could someone explain what exactly this code is doing?**

```
function ProjAABB_Concave(x,y,obj,t)
{       
    //if distance from "innermost" corner of AABB is further than tile radius,
    //collision is occuring and we need to project

    var signx = t.signx;
    var signy = t.signy;

    var ox = (t.pos.x + (signx*t.xw)) - (obj.pos.x - (signx*obj.xw));//(ox,oy) is the vector form the innermost AABB corner to the
    var oy = (t.pos.y + (signy*t.yw))- (obj.pos.y - (signy*obj.yw));//circle's center

    var twid = t.xw*2;
    var rad = Math.sqrt(twid*twid + 0);//this gives us the radius of a circle centered on the tile's corner and extending to the opposite edge of the tile;
                                        //note that this should be precomputed at compile-time since it's constant

    var len = Math.sqrt(ox*ox + oy*oy);
    var pen = len - rad;
    if(0 < pen)
    {
        //collision; we need to either project along the axes, or project along corner->circlecenter vector

        var lenP = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
        if(lenP < pen)
        {
            //it's shorter to move along axis directions
            obj.ReportCollisionVsWorld(x,y,x/lenP, y/lenP, t);

            return COL_AXIS;
        }
        else
        {
            //project along corner->circle vector
            ox /= len;//len should never be 0, since if it IS 0, rad should be > than len
            oy /= len;//and we should never reach here

            obj.ReportCollisionVsWorld(ox*pen, oy*pen, ox, oy, t);

            return COL_OTHER;
        }

    }

    return COL_NONE;

}
```

Comment: well it's obviously very, very, poor collision code.  Computing *Math.sqrt* for both *len* and *rad* and then *lenP* is downright stupid: compare directly the **SQUARED** sums.  That's game collision detection 101.  Really.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r : I got you but if you see the speed/smoothness of this game is pretty fast due these precalculated math that's why it tempted me to go through this tutorial. However could you please suggest any tutorial for handling collision between AABB and convex/concave.Apart from following this tutorial I have implemented separate axis based collision detection but it works only for convex shapes not for rounded shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple sphere-vs-sphere collision. See the part where they do

```
var pen = len - rad;
if(0 < pen)
```

They are just checking that the "t" object radius minus the current object radius are touching (=0) or crossing (<0).

The part where they do

```
var ox = (t.pos.x + (signx*t.xw)) - (obj.pos.x - (signx*obj.xw));//(ox,oy) is the vector form the innermost AABB corner to the
var oy = (t.pos.y + (signy*t.yw))- (obj.pos.y - (signy*obj.yw));//circle's center
```

They are moving the "t" object to "obj" frame of reference.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: It's a tutorial pal, no need to point out its pitfalls (in the long run Anandh will probably find out he can used radiuses squared).

Comment: If they are checking the radius (distance between center of two object == sum radius of two object) , my question is how are able to use this approach to find the collision between one sided curved shape "please refer to - Figure 6".

Comment: They collide both objects as if they were two spheres. The rectangle "sphere" is the imaginary "sphere" from the center to the corner, if there's an intersection of both spheres they check that the distance between the rectangle's corner and the concave radius is near enough to collide. To rule out the corner of the concave object, if the rectangle's sphere radius is > len then len - rad will be less than 0 and no collision will be made :)

Comment: now I understood the code along with your description , now am curious to know what is wrong with this collision code. One more question is how perform collision detection on curved surface (like Locoroco game worlk)?

Comment: @Anandh : The bad things on this code are: 1) extensive use of `Math.sqrt`, you could use everything squared and voila; and 2) The `signx*obj.xw` you could use a conditional sign change on a local var, less expensive that a multiplication. Take into account that these "bad things" are only bad if you're using this code to collide thousands of objects or if your code is going to run on a mobile platform (computing power drains battery faster).

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much better to show the underlying physical algorithm, then you can understand code faster